# Getting error when Executing sp_configure 'max server memory'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I want to set max server memory, I am getting the bellow error message:

> The configuration option 'max server memory' does not exist, or it may
>   be an advanced option

sql query is as follow:

```
exec sp_configure 'max server memory', 1024
reconfigure
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, it's telling you that's an advanced option

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 1024;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

You may want to read **[`Server Memory Configuration Options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you the problem here, it's an advanced setting and you haven't enabled them. A search would have led you to the documentation: [Example A. Set the max server memory option to 4 GB.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-2017#examples)
:

> The following example sets the max server memory option to 4 GB. Note
>   that although sp_configure specifies the name of the option as max
>   server memory (MB), the example demonstrates omitting the (MB).
>
> ```
> sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
> GO
> RECONFIGURE;
> GO
> sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;
> GO
> RECONFIGURE;
> GO
> ```

Do you really want to set the Memory to 1GB though? That's nothing for SQL Server to "play" with; you're very likely going to have performance issues.